# Easier way to use csv file with jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

stackoverflow.csv:

```
name,age,country
Dutchie, 10, Netherlands
Germie, 20, Germany
Swisie, 30, Switzerland
```

stackoverflow.j2:

```
Name: {{ name }}
Age: {{ age }}
Country: {{ country }}

#####
```

Python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


import csv
from jinja2 import Template
import time


source_file = "stackoverflow.csv"
template_file = "stackoverflow.j2"

# String that will hold final full text
full_text = ""


# Open up the Jinja template file (as text) and then create a Jinja Template Object
with open(template_file) as f:
    template = Template(f.read(), keep_trailing_newline=True)

# Open up the CSV file containing the data
with open(source_file) as f:
    # Use DictReader to access data from CSV
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    # For each row in the CSV, generate a configuration using the jinja template
    for row in reader:
        text = template.render(
            name=row["name"],
            age=row["age"],
            country=row["country"]
        )
        # Append this text to the full text
        full_text += text

output_file = f"{template_file.split('.')[0]}_{source_file.split('.')[0]}.txt"

# Save the final configuration to a file
with open(output_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(full_text)
```

output:

```
Name: Dutchie
Age:  10
Country:  Netherlands

#####

Name: Germie
Age:  20
Country:  Germany

#####

Name: Swisie
Age:  30
Country:  Switzerland

#####
```

See the script and input file above. Everything is **working** at the moment, but I would like to **optimize** the script that when I add a **new column** in the **CSV file**, I **don'**t need to add the script.
Example: when I add to the CSV file the column **"address"**, I would need the update the **template.render** with the following:

```
text = template.render(
                name=row["name"],
                age=row["age"],
                country=row["country"],
                address=row["address"]

            )
```

Is there a way to do this more efficient? I once had a code example to do this, but I cannot find it anymore :(.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the dict into key and value variables in a for loop with `items()`.

```py
{% for key, value in row.items() %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can also pass the list of rows to the template and use another for loop so that you only have to render the template once.